# Absolute continuity implies the limit goes to zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, absolute-continuity

If $f=f(x)$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$ such that $f' \in L^2([0,1])$ and $f(0)=0$. Prove then that

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}=0$$

The hint says to use Fundamental theorem of calculus but I don't see where to use that.

I know if $f' \in L^2([0,1])$ then

$$\bigg(\int_{[0,1]} \vert f'(x) \vert^{2} dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}} < + \infty.$$

I don't know what to do from here though. Any hints would be appreciated. Am I merely using L'Hôpital's rule, since I get $0/0$?

Comment: Yes, you have to use the fact that $f(x) = \int_0^x f'(t)dt$ a.e., and use an inequality that will involve $\int_0^x f'(t)^2 dt$, which is bounded by a finite quantity. Can you think of such an inequality?

Comment: bound it by triangle inequality?

Comment: No, that would be way too weak. Indeed, the answer is below : the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (or Holder for a specific case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x > 0$, using the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$
\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \right| &= \left| \frac{\int_0^x f^\prime(t)dt}{\sqrt{x}} \right| \\
&\leq \frac{\int |\mathbb{1}_{[0,x]}(t) f^\prime (t)| dt}{\sqrt{x}} \\
&= \frac{\|1_{[0,x]} f^\prime\|_1}{\sqrt{x}} \\
&\leq \frac{x \|f^\prime\|_2}{\sqrt{x}} \\
&= \sqrt{x} \|f^\prime\|_2\\
&\to 0
\end{align*}$$
as $x \to 0^+$, where the last inequality is Hölder's inequality.

Comment: I see, and by $1_{[0,x]}$ you're referring to the indicator function on $[0,1]$, correct?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame That's correct